# beamerappendixnote does not work with \pause

Tags: beamer, appendix

I use `beamerappendixnote` to manage backup slides in beamer, for maintaining a useful code structure without manually fiddling with beamergotobuttons. One problem is that it does not seem to work in combination with `\pause`.

When there are `\pause`s, each appendix slide exists as many times as there are steps on the slide it is created on.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[20pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerappendixnote}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Main title}
        \pause Main \pause content \pause \vfill
        \appxnote{Note title}{Note content}
    \end{frame}
    \printappxnotes
\end{document}
```

**Problem**:

1. The appendix slide is repeated 4 times
2. Hyperlinks "back" do not work.

**Ideal solutions** (by order of usefulness):

- Code that works with `beamerappendixnote` as is
- Patch to `beamerappendixnote` that fixes this
- Alternative package that only requires code inside the frame or the preamble

PS: I do not want to stop using `\pause`, because `\only<>{}`, etc are much harder to integrate with my markdown workflow. And also seem to not really fix the problem.

Comment: Related but separate question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/661651/beamerappendixnote-does-not-work-with-fragile-verbatim-context

Answer (score 2):

Same as for your other question: use the `beamersubframe` package to keep your notes near your main slides:

```
\documentclass[20pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[append]{beamersubframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[label=foo]
    \frametitle{Main title}
       \pause Main \pause content \pause \vfill
       \hyperlink{bar}{\beamerbutton{Appendix}}
    \end{frame}
    \begin{subframe}[label=bar]
    \frametitle{Note title}
    \hyperlink{foo}{\beamerbutton{Back}}  Note content
    \end{subframe}
    \begin{frame}
    normal frame
    \end{frame}
    
    \appendsubframes
\end{document}
```

---

If you want to keep `beamerappendixnote`, you can make sure the command is only executed once like this:

```
\documentclass[20pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerappendixnote}


\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Main title}
        \pause Main \pause content \pause \vfill
        \only<1>{\appxnote{Note title}{Note content}}
    \end{frame}
    \printappxnotes
\end{document}
```

Comment: I like the second part of your solution. Sadly with `\only<1>` coming after the `\pause` the button is actually never shown. I tried using `<\value{beamerpauses}->` then it works a little. Unfortunately, it seems to break the hyperlinks.

Comment: I made some changes to the question to be more specific for the bounty, which implicitly exclude the possibility of using `subframe`. I'm just writing this comment to document that this answer was provided when this was not yet clear.