# beamerappendixnote does not work with [fragile] / verbatim context

Tags: beamer, verbatim, fragile

I use `beamerappendixnote` to provide code examples in my lecture slides, for students who want to redo what we did in class.

Putting code on slides with nice highlighting, etc., requires the `[fragile]` option for frames. That does not seem to work with `beamerappendixnote`.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[20pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[backposition=title]{beamerappendixnote}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Main title}
        Main content \vfill
        \appxnote[fragile]{Long note}{\lipsum[3]}
    \end{frame}
    \printappxnotes
\end{document}
```

**Problem:**

Error message, because the `beamerappendixnote` does not accept `[fragile]`

**Ideal solutions** (by order of usefulness):

- Code that works with `beamerappendixnote` as is
- Patch to `beamerappendixnote` that fixes this
- Alternative package that would also automatically manage the `\beamergotobuttons`

Any pointers on who to get `fragile` frames  with such appendix slides is highly welcome.

Comment: Related but separate question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/661650/beamerappendixnote-does-not-work-with-pause

Comment: Even if the macro would accept the `fragile` option, you wouldn't be able to use fragile content like code into the argument of any macro.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `subframe` package instead to keep your code examples near your main slides

```
\documentclass[20pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[append]{beamersubframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[label=foo]
        \frametitle{Main title}
        Main content 
        \hyperlink{bar}{\beamerbutton{Appendix}}
    \end{frame}
    \begin{subframe}[fragile,label=bar]
    \hyperlink{foo}{\beamerbutton{Back}} 
    \begin{lstlisting}
    test
    \end{lstlisting}
    \end{subframe}
    \begin{frame}
    normal frame
    \end{frame}
    
    \appendsubframes
\end{document}
```

This also works with markdown:

````
---
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    keep_tex: true
header-includes:
  - \usepackage[append]{beamersubframe}
  - \usepackage{listings}
  - \makeatletter\beamer@ignorenonframefalse\makeatother
  - \AtEndDocument{\appendsubframes}
---

test \label{foo}\hyperlink{bar}{\beamerbutton{Appendix}}

``` {=latex}
\end{frame}
    \begin{subframe}[fragile,label=bar]
    \hyperlink{foo}{\beamerbutton{Back}} 
    \begin{lstlisting}
    test
    \end{lstlisting}
    \end{subframe}
\begin{frame}
```

test
````

Comment: Thanks, that's already very helpful for other people with similar problems. The problem for my case would only be that I'd need to edit the code in TWO places (add the beanergotobuttons inside the frame and add the subframe outside of it). Unfortunately, this does not work in my setup, where I use markdown/pandoc, which requires me to add the code for the appendix-slides in a single location in the code. Or is there a way to automatically add the \beamergotobutton to the previous frames, without editing the code inside that frame?

Comment: @sheß this works also in markdown. You can add code in between frames with this trick: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58645326/2777074

Comment: Thanks, but this would still require me to manually set/maintain the beamer goto buttons. with my beamerappendixnote can simply have a lua filter that wraps all level-4 headings into `\appxnote{heading title}{ ... }` which is convenient,b because I can move slides in and out of the appendix simply by changing "### heading" to  "#### heading". if possible i'd like to maintain that.

Comment: @sheß As long as the additional content is at the end of your frame, your lua filter could change `####  xxx` to `\label{foo}\hyperlink{bar}{\beamerbutton{Appendix}}

\`\`\` {=latex}
\end{frame}
    \begin{subframe}[fragile,label=bar]
    \hyperlink{foo}{\beamerbutton{Back}} 
    \begin{lstlisting}
    xxx
    \end{lstlisting}
    \end{subframe}
\begin{frame}
\`\`\`` can't it (an maybe some numeric label...)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This is true but I think (1) this does not works if i have more than 1 appendix slide and (2) the loose `\begin{frame}` might be a problem. it creates an empty slide if this is the end of the document (or the end of a [sub]section in `bookdown::beamer_presentation2`)