Footnotes in beamer with beamerappendixnote
Is there a way to remove the footnotes & footcites on the actual slides and only have them shown on the slides generated with \printappxnotes?
Here's a picture to hopefully make it a bit more clear what I want to achieve:

Thanks a lot in advance for any help!
MWE
\documentclass[20pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerappendixnote}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[border shrink=1mm]
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{3}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{4}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}}

\begin{document}
  
\begin{frame}{Footnote}
  A footnote \appxnote{The footnote appendix slide \footnote{Foo}}{Bar}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Footcite}
  A footcite \appxnote{The footcite appendix slide \footcite{westfahl:space}}{Bar}
\end{frame}

\printappxnotes

\end{document}


You could hide the footnote from the actual frame like this:
\documentclass[20pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerappendixnote}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[border shrink=1mm]
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{3}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{4}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}}

\newif\ifappnotes

\begin{document}
  
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Footnote}
  A footnote \appxnote{The footnote appendix slide\ifappnotes\footnote{Foo}\fi}{Bar}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Footcite}
  A footcite \appxnote{The footcite appendix slide\ifappnotes\footcite{westfahl:space}\fi}{Bar}
\end{frame}

\appnotestrue
\printappxnotes

\end{document}



Great, thanks - I suppose this is probably the best way to go, or is there a way that is more global so that I don't have to manually check for \ifappnotes every time?

@user20478285 Personally I would probably use the beamersubframe package instead. It seems more robust and would avoid such problems in the first place. Here a short example how to get a similar setup: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/661654/36296
